# nodeBuilder() is removed by Elasticsearch, but still spring-data-elasticsearch documentation contains configuration which uses nodeBuilder()

Tags: spring-boot, elasticsearch, spring-data

I was following the [Spring-Data-Elasticseach documentaion](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/elasticsearch/docs/current/reference/html/#elasticsearch.annotation) and was following the configuration as mentioned in the above link.

```
@Configuration
@EnableElasticsearchRepositories(basePackages = "org/springframework/data/elasticsearch/repositories")
static class Config {

    @Bean
    public ElasticsearchOperations elasticsearchTemplate() {
        return new ElasticsearchTemplate(nodeBuilder().local(true).node().client());
    }
}
```

Since import for `nodeBuilder()` is not mentioned in the documentation I assumed it from `org.elasticsearch.node.NodeBuilder.*` as mentioned in [elasticsearch Java API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api/2.0/node-client.html).

But in the later releases, the API got changed and `NodeBuilder` no longer exists. So why/how the spring documentation still using the `NodeBuilder`?

If that's an issue with the documentation, what's the right configuration?

The dependencies I am using

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-elasticsearch</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

with the boot version `2.1.1.RELEASE`

Answer (score 2):

This looks like a documentation issue. I've raise [DATAES-574](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAES-574) to have that fixed.

With Spring Boot 2.1, the usual way to create a `Client` bean is to set a `spring.data.elasticsearch.cluster-nodes` property. Behind the scenes this will create the `Client` as a `org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClient` instance.

You can also define that bean yourself if you so wish.

In the future, `TransportClient` is also going to been deprecated by Elasticsearch. At that point you'll need to use the higher level REST API. See https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAES-407 for the details.

Comment: Thanks Phil. The ticket for `Java High Level REST Client` support is **closed** in oct,2018 but I don't see any documentation regarding that. You also said that "Behind the scenes this will create the Client as a org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClient instance"... But why? Any reason you are aware of?

Comment: I think the documentation is provided by Elastic (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-rest/master/java-rest-high.html). I'm not sure if there is still Spring Data documentation updates pending. It might be worth raising an issue for that.

Comment: For the use of `org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClient` take a look at [this code](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/v2.1.4.RELEASE/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/data/elasticsearch/ElasticsearchAutoConfiguration.java#L54-L62). That was just the recommended API at the time we released Spring Boot 2.1